# How do I add child resources when the parent resource was created inside a Bicep module

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-bicep

I have this Bicep code...

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

module autacc './../bicepmodules/BICEP/modules/automationAccount.bicep' = {
  name: 'automationaccount'
  params : {
    applicationName: 'replen'
    environmentType: 'Development'
    tagDescription: 'test'
    userName : 'user'
    location: location
}
}

resource aa 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2022-08-08' existing = {
  name: autacc.name 
  resource webhook1 'webhooks@2015-10-31' = {
    name: 'AutoReplen_CreateOrders_webhook'
    properties:{
        isEnabled: true
        runbook:{
        }
    }
  }

}
```

This results in the following error...

```
 The deployment 'main3' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'automationaccount' not found. (Code:ParentResourceNotFound)
```

I can verify from looking at the deployments blade in the Portal that this error is related to the 'AutoReplen_CreateOrders' resource.

Also, because this has been run multiple times, the automation account has been created, so the error is not due to the fact that its trying to create the runbook before the automation account has been created.

How do I resolve?

Content of module as requested.

```
param applicationName string

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Username that will be recorded in the tags of the object')
param userName string

@description('A description that will be recorded in the tags')
param  tagDescription string

param CreatedOnDate string = utcNow()

@allowed([
  'Production'
  'Test'
  'Development'
  'UAT'
]
)
@description('Environment')
param environmentType string

@description('A 3 digit number, default is 001')
@allowed([
  '001'
  '002'
  '003'
  '004'
  '005'
  '006'
  '007'
  '008'
  '009'
  'NOTSPECIFIED'
])
param instanceNumber string = 'NOTSPECIFIED'

@description('An array containing roleDefinitionid, principalId and principalType.  Pass 0 or more objects for each role assignment required.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/scenarios-rbac?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003674')
param roleAssignments array = []

//param runBookName string

//param scheduleName string

var shortEnv = environmentType == 'Production' ? 'prod' : environmentType == 'Development' ? 'dev' : environmentType == 'Test' ? 'test' : 'other'
var automationAccountName = 'aa-${applicationName}-${shortEnv}-${location}${instanceNumber == 'NOTSPECIFIED' ? '' : '-${instanceNumber}'}'

resource autaccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2021-06-22' = {
  name: automationAccountName
  location: location
  tags: {
    CreatedBy: userName
    CreatedOnDate : CreatedOnDate
    Description : tagDescription
    DeploymentInfo : 'deployed by Bicep module ${deployment().name}'
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  
  properties: {
    disableLocalAuth: false
    encryption: {
      identity: {
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Automation'
    }
    publicNetworkAccess: false
    sku: {
      name: 'Basic'
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Return the automation account name from the module:

```
// automationAccount.bicep

...
output name string = automationAccountName
```

2. Create the webhook from a module:

```
// automationAccountWebhook.bicep

param automationAccountName string
param webHookName string

resource automationAccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2022-08-08' existing = {
  name: automationAccountName
}

resource webhook1 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks@2015-10-31' = {
  parent : automationAccount
  name: webHookName
  properties:{
      isEnabled: true
      runbook:{
      }
  }
}
```

3. From your main, you could invoke the module like that:

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

module autacc './../bicepmodules/BICEP/modules/automationAccount.bicep' = {
  name: 'automationaccount'
  params : {
    applicationName: 'replen'
    environmentType: 'Development'
    tagDescription: 'test'
    userName : 'user'
    location: location
  }
}

module webhook1 './../bicepmodules/BICEP/modules/automationAccountWebhook.bicep' = {
  name: 'webhook'
  params : {
    automationAccountName: autacc.outputs.name
    webHookName: 'AutoReplen_CreateOrders_webhook'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I have done that, I think my code is equivilent to what you put, but I get the same error

Comment: would you be able to share the content fo your module as well ?

Comment: Sure, I have added that above

Comment: in your main, the name of the automation account is the name of the module: `name: autacc.name` => `automationaccount`. You would need to output the name of the automation from your module.

Comment: I dont think I can do that as I am creating the name of the automation account in the module, I only pass in the 'applicationName' rather than the full name.  When I try to use the name from the output to create the runbook, it says it requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment.  It wont accept me passing in autacc.outputs.aaname.

Comment: I am thinking the reason this is not working is that the name cannot be calculated at the start.  So I have changed my module not to construct the resource name, but to take a string as a parameter.  But I am still have trouble referring to it when created a sub resource, such as a runbook or webhook.  How should I reference this, in the parent parameter?

Comment: have you tried my updated answer ? it should work even if the name is constructed inside the module